# How to create and initialize an array on the stack in Assembly?

Tags: assembly, nasm

I can do the following to create and initialize an array to be a global variable:

```
    section .data
s DB 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 0
```

But I want to create and initialize an array on the stack (to be used in my function). I would guess this is how to reserve space for it:

```
sub esp, 6
```

but how can I initialize it?

Comment: Write a series of bytes, words and/or dwords containing the characters to the stack. Though you might save space by keeping a copy of the string somewhere (e.g. in the data section) and just copying the data to the stack using `rep movsb`.

Answer (score 3):

```
s DB 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 0
```

To setup this array in the stack you could use

```
mov ax,'o'
push ax
mov ax,'ll'
push ax
mov ax,'he'
push ax     ;Now SP points to 'hello',0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate contents of stack by its pointers, esb and ebp.
For example for reserving 3 words and initialize them to zero you can write:

```
push ebp
sub esp, 6
mov ebp, esp
mov [ebp], 0
add ebp, 2
mov [ebp], 0
add ebp, 2
mov [ebp], 0
```

or

```
sub esp, 6
mov [esp], 0
mov [esp+2], 0
mov [esp+4], 0
```